# XCOPY copy file but not overwrite

Tags: visual-studio, xcopy, post-build-event

I'm using XCOPY in a post-build event to copy some files to the bin directory. However, I don't want to overwrite when the file is already up to date. How can I do that?

sample:

```
echo F | xcopy /y "$(ProjectDir)..\Files\MyFile.ini" "$(TargetDir)"
```

Comment: Well, surely you *do* want to overwrite when the .ini file was changed.  Use the `/d` option, xcopy will skip the copy if the target file is up to date.

Comment: Oh, thank you, it worked. Why you didn't post as answer?

Comment: Because you asked the wrong question.  Why you didn't edit it after that comment is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Use the **/d** option, xcopy will skip the copy if the target file is up to date". Answer from comments.